# What is the correct structure for this sentence (IT)

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, syntactic-analysis

XYZ Servers are small machines used to facilitate ABCD.  They are automatically launched and discarded on your hosting account as needed.

XYZ Servers are small machines used to facilitate ABCD.  They are automatically launched and discarded as needed on your hosting account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify: the difference between the two sentences is the order of the two phrases *as needed*, and *on your hosting account*. I would say in this context there is no difference. The servers are both launched and discarded, both as needed and on your hosting account.

Unlike for adjectives, there is no general order of multiple prepositional phrases.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean they are discarded when it is needed on your hosting account, then the latter. If you mean they are discarded on your account then the first one.